# If $A\leq B$ or $B\leq A$ for any $A,B\leq G$ then $G$ is a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question is :

Suppose $G$ is a $p$ group ($|G|=p^n$)and $A\leq B$ or $B\leq A$ for any $A,B\leq G$ then, Prove that $G$ is cyclic.

Suppose $A,B$ are two subgroups of $G$ of same order (say $p^m$ for some $m<n$)

As we have $A\leq B$  or $B\leq A$, in any case we can not have $A$ properly contained in $B$ (or the other way). Thus, we should have $A=B$.

I mean no two subgroups having same order can be different.

Thus, I see any subgroup is normal (As $|gAg^{-1}|=|A|$ for any $g\in G$).

Any subgroup is normal... This does not even say that $G$ is abelian :( :(..

Highly disappointed with this... But, as i think this is the only "considerable conclusion" i have concluded from given data I think i will include in the question..

I would be thankful if someone can suggest me an approach/ give me a hint to approach the problem....

Thank You

EDIT : Just after this Question it is sited that :

> "This Statement is also true without the assumption that $G$ is a p-group"

As now, I have understood the proof for p-groups, I would like to work on the general statement.

I would be thankful if some one can give hint for general statement "preferably an extension of this proof"

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $G$ is necessarily a $p$-group since if $p,q\mid |G|$ where $p,q$ were distinct primes, then $\langle x\rangle\leqslant\langle y\rangle$ or $
\langle y\rangle\leqslant\langle x\rangle$ would be impossible for $|x|=p$ and $|y|=q$. But, then note that since $G$ is a $p$-group it has a subgroup of every order dividing $|G|$. But, from the assumption, it can have at most one subgroup of every order dividing $|G|$. Thus, $G$ has precisely one subgroup of every order dividing $|G|$, and so it must be cyclic. So, the $G$ (finite) that satisfy your condition are cyclic $p$-groups.

> **Theorem:** *If $G$ is a finite group of order $n$ such that for every $d\mid n$, $G$ has at most one subgroup of order $d$, then $G$ is cyclic.*

*Proof:* Partition $G$ into classes $C_d$ according to the order $d$ of its elements. Evidently then, if $G$ has $s_d$ number of cyclic subgroups of order $d$, then $\#(C_d)=\varphi(d)s_d$. But, note that

$$|G|=\sum_{d\mid n}\#(C_d)=\sum_{d\mid n}s_d\varphi(d)$$

Since

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)=n$$

it follows from the fact that $s_d\leqslant 1$, that $s_d=1$ for all $d$. In particular, $s_n=1$, so there exists a cyclic subgroup of $G$ of order $n$. So, $G$ is cyclic.

**EDIT:** Prompted by Mikko's comment below, I think it's nice that with a little oomph, we can actually classify all groups, finite or infinite, that satisfy the property in the title.

Namely, let $G$ be any group that satisfies the titular property. Note that $G$ is necessarily abelian. Indeed, if $g,h\in G$ then either $\langle g\rangle\leqslant\langle h\rangle$ or $\langle h\rangle\leqslant \langle g\rangle$ and so evidently $g$ and $h$ commute. If $G$ is an f.g. group satisfying the titular property, it must evidently be torsion. Indeed, since $G$ is abelian it suffices to show that it has rank $0$. But, since the titular property is obvious hereditary, and $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't satisfy the titular property, it follows that $\text{rank}(G)=0$. Thus, $G=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n$ and some prime $p$.

Now, let $G$ be any group satisfying the titular property. The above now shows that $G$ is abelian and every finitely generated subgroup of $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$. Recall that $G=\varinjlim F$, where $F$ varies over the diagram of finitely generated subgroups. Now, the above shows that each finitely generated subgroup is of the form $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ and that they are all contained in one another. By the infinitude of $G$, we may actually see that $G$ contains $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$, and so the diagram of finitely generated subgroups is

$$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\to\cdots$$

thus,

$$G=\varinjlim F=\varinjlim \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$$

(where $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)=\varinjlim\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is the [Prufer $p$-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group)). Thus, the only groups $G$ which satisfy the titular properties are:

1. The groups $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ for $p$ a prime.
2. The Prufer $p$-group $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ for $p$ a prime.

Comment: could you please eloborate  your statement "G has precisely one subgroup of every order dividing |G|, and so it must be cyclic"... the statement that $G$ having precisely one subgroup of every order dividing $|G|$ is already conlcuded in my question itself... I want to conclude from that $G$ is cyclic... could you please explain that..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik See my edi.t

Comment: I got it.. :) It took so much for me to understand (i am not sure if i have missed something).. but, finally i am happy :) btw, do you really mean (and need) "since G is a p-group it has a subgroup of every order dividing |G|"...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes, it's a stonger form of Sylow's Theorem. The converse of Lagrange's theorem is true for prime powers. If $p^m\mid|G|$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^m$. See these notes by Keith Conrad for example: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/sylowpf.pdf. Do you need it, no. I just thought it was nice. The theorem I stated actually solves your problem directly, the $p$-group part is needed if you want to make it an "iff".

Comment: Thanks for giving me another result... I could not found that in those notes.. I will try myself to work it out.. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik For reference, it's at the end of page 3. It's headed under "<b>Proof of Sylow I</b>"

Comment: yes.. I have just seen it now.... i have not seen the proof yet.. I like the result so want to work on my own.. I would definitely ask for help if there is any problem :)

Comment: By the way, the only infinite group with this property is the Prüfer $p$-group.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen Is that because the above shows that for all finitely generated (clearly no such group with the above property can have a free part, so the above actually does show this) subgroups of such a $G$ we have that $G=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n$, and in fact, shows all such $p$ exist. So, we have the natural inclusions $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}$. Since any group is the direct limit of its f.g. subgroups we have that $G=\varinjlim \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$?

Comment: @AlexYoucis : I do not understand most of the Edited part as of now.. But i hope i will learn some more theory and try reading this again.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your very first line. (**Addendum:** if you mean that in a cyclic group any two subgroups are comparable, this is only true in cyclic $p$-groups. Check the cyclic group of order $6$ to see why your argument fails.)

As to the rest, if $G$ has only one maximal subgroup $M$, then clearly any $x \in G \setminus M$ generates $G$, as $\langle x \rangle \not\le M$.

Now if $A$ and $B$ are two maximal subgroups of $G$, one can be contained in the other only if they are equal.

Comment: yes, yes... Now i understood... I mean i understood where  have gone wrong... In general, in a cyclic groups any two groups are not necessarily comparable...

Comment: So, the conclusion $G$ is cyclic has nothing to do with $p$ group??? nothing to do with uniqueness of subgroups of given order??? Iam confused...

Comment: **Proposition** Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose that for any $A, B \le G$ you have either $A \le B$ or $B \le A$. Then $G$ is cyclic, of prime-power order.

Comment: I proved the first part of the statement of the above proposition. As to the second part, one can note that if $G =\langle a \rangle$ is finite and cyclic, and $p \ne q$ are two primes dividing its order, then $\langle a^{p} \rangle$ and  $\langle a^{q} \rangle$ are two distinct maximal subgroups.

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of your question is false, I think. Consider $\def\Z{\mathbb Z}\Z_6$ and $A=\{0,2,4\} \leq \Z_6$ and $B=\{0,3\}\leq \Z_6$ - none of $A,B$ is a subgroup of the other.

Comment: And where the proof is wrong is "depending on whether $m<n$ or $n<m$ we will have either $A\leq B$ or $B\leq A$": you have to consider whether $m \mid n$ or $n\mid m$ to conclude such a thing. In the example @savicko1 gave, if $n$ and $m$ are coprime, the group $x^m$ and $x^n$ generate intersect trivially.

Comment: I thank you for pointing out my mistake. Thank you :) I will edit that :)